# ArrayList<Event> result size is 0 in android studio

Tags: java, android, arraylist

why is it the result.size is giving me a zero value? Is my arraylist resets? or i need to initialize my variable 'result'?

here's my code:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Event> result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "result " + (result.size()),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            int day = Integer.parseInt(result.get(i).getDay());  //25
            int month = Integer.parseInt(result.get(i).getMonth()); //12
            int year = Integer.parseInt(result.get(i).getYear()); // 1988

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.set(year, month-1, day, 0, 0);
            Date greenDate = c.getTime();


            if (caldroidFragment != null) {

                caldroidFragment.setBackgroundResourceForDate(R.color.BlueViolet, greenDate);

            }

        }

    }
}
```

}

and here's my model class :

```
  private class GetEvents extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Event>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Event> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        events.clear();

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Event event = new Event();

                event.setEVENT(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE)));
                event.setLOCATION(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION)));
                event.setDESCRIPTION(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION)));
                event.setStartDate(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART)));
                event.setEndDate(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND)));

                events.add(event);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
            c.close();
        }

        return events;
    }
```

Can anyone help me? Please, I'm having a hard time coding this.

Comment: can you show how you are calling `doInBackground` and how this result is being passed to `onPostExecute`

Comment: I call my doinbackground in my onMonthChange,  new GetEvents.execute(); oh I think the problem is the result didnt pass anything, right? I declared only that result as variable in my arraylist, am I doing wrong?

Comment: yes that is possible, or maybe you are trying to access list before it finish task. getevents extends asynctask class if you are running asynctask and you are treating it as synchronous task, then you dont have result, my suggestion is add logs to see what exactly happened

Comment: Please self-answer and mark it as answered or remove the question.